# How to use Excel formulas in C#

Tags: c#, excel, chi-squared

I want to calculate Right-tailed probability of chi-squared distribution in C#. 
Excel can do this calculation using following code

```
= CHISQ.DIST.RT(100,4)
```

where 100 is chi-squared and 4 is the degree of freedom.

I want to use this function in C# to the calculation; I tried adding reference to "Microsoft.Office.Interop" but I could not find a way to use it !

I came across to some topics of how to use C# to do formulations in Excel and get the results in Excel, but unfortunately this is not what I need; I need to do the calculation in C# and get the results in C#.

Comment: Have you created and excel worksheet using the Interop library?

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to use Excel?  You should be able to easily port this to C#.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432194/How-to-Calculate-the-Chi-Squared-P-Value

Comment: I checked this code before. I'm dealing with ChIP-seq data, where Chi-squared is, lets say, 300 ! which the corresponding p-value is about 2.00E-30 ! That code gives NaN or Infinity for these numbers; but excel simply gives very accurate results, thats why I prefer to use Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only wanting to a calculation that is similar to the Excel calculation, you should consider @korolewi's suggested comment.

If you have to actually use Excel's engine, you can do

1. What the previous poster suggested, but that would require an instance of Excel to be installed on the web server and it would launch Excel each time the code is executed, etc. It is bad practice and unsupported by Microsoft
2. Use a third party tool like Aspose.com's Cells. With that you could set the formula, calculate it, and get the value from the wookbook without actually opening Excel on the server.

Comment: I agree, if you need to evaluate Excel formulas but not necessarily with Excel itself (and especially if this is being done on a non-interactive machine such as a server, though you don't mention if this is the case) a third-party tool is the way to go.  As best as I can tell Aspose.Cells does not support the CHISQ.DIST.RT function.  SpreadsheetGear 2012 for .NET supports CHISQ.DIST.RT along all of the other functions introduced in Excel 2010.  Disclaimer: I work for SpreadsheetGear as a technical support engineer.

Comment: I appreciate the SpreadsheetGear suggestion. But is not there any method using the formulas without using any third-party apps ?

Comment: I would hardly consider using an external library as a third party app, so yes. The link in the comment to your original question points to the way to do it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432194/How-to-Calculate-the-Chi-Squared-P-Value has DLLs that you can use to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To work with a "virtual" Excel within your C#-code using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, you have to create a workbook object, create (at least) one worksheet object on this workbook - and then you can use Excel functions out of the Interop-box.

Comment: The question clearly says "I need to do the calculations in C# and get the results in C#", and that doing it using Excel is **not** what they need. Creating an Excel workbook when the question is about NOT using Excel is obviously not the answer.

Comment: @KenWhite It is definitely not the answer but this at least answers the question oh how much intense grunt work you need to do just go call a worksheet function. Result: This is not the desirable approach.

Comment: If it's not an answer, it shouldn't be posted as one. It would possibly be a useful comment, but answers should do just that - provide an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @KenWhite , as you mentioned, I don't want to use Excel workbook. Simply using Excel workbook would not be efficient for me, because I need to do this calculation for about 1,000,000 times each run; therefore I MUST use more efficient methods as possible.

Comment: @KenWhite This may not be the answer of the last part, but it can be a help at this point: "I tried adding reference to "Microsoft.Office.Interop" but I could not find a way to use it!". And also "How to use Excel formulas in C#" - not "calculate something in C# similar to the implementation in Excel".

Although the OP said in the last sentence "I need [...] calculation in C# and get the results in C#", they added "excel simply gives very accurate results, thats why I prefer to use Excel" in a comment.

So, this answer **can** be helpful and is wide away from "clearly not the answer". :)

Comment: @user947889 **You can't call an Excel function directly** - you have to go through a worksheet.  So you need to decide which is more important - a native implementation that can handle the scale and precision you need, or the inefficiency of creating a worksheet to process the calculations.